# Community wiki?

Tags: support, faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Community Wiki?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/what-is-community-wiki)

I see "community wiki" mentioned, and I gather it is the place we put questions that are interesting but are more polls or lists rather than those that have a right answer. But I can't find anything about community wiki in the FAQ. Where do I learn more about it? How do I find all the questions that have been so designated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most canonical source for [**what are community wiki posts?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: Great, that is indeed the most useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for "wiki:1", like this: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=Wiki%3A1 a community wiki question does not award reputation for anyone involved. It's used to indicate a poll or big list where users can freely edit the question and answers with the intent of the question being a long lived resource rather than a specific question with a "right answer".

Once you see what the CW questions look like, you'll understand what is one and what isn't one.

Comment: Great, thank you! How would we go about having this info added to the FAQ?

Comment: @Michael: It also has lower reputation requirements for editing. Another thing to keep in mind is that community wiki doesn't magically make crap questions acceptable. I judge many rather harshly especially if it's something I consider stupid or off-topic like "What's your favorite recipe?". Others I think offer a clear benefit, such as the cookbook one. I like this because, while subjective, it serves as a sort-of counter-balance to the off-topicness of recipe requests.