# Does flagging for "community wiki" still make sense?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have just flagged [ideas-for-a-sweet-pizza](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/ideas-for-a-sweet-pizza) even after reading [what-is-community-wiki](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/what-is-community-wiki) here and found that we can't create CW anymore.

What should we do with questions like that? If it's not CW it might be closer to a question that doesn't belong here than to a question with a reasonable objective answer. However, I still find the question interesting...

Answer (score 2):

Julio, I debated using a close vote on that question, but decided not to for the following reasons:

1. The poster has already done his homework and is not asking us for a recipe.  He has an idea in mind.
2. While others are not treating it as such, the question should be read as how to create a pizza sweet enough for dessert that still LOOKS like a pizza.  That's a pretty narrow category that reminds me of the famous dessert sushi question on this site.  It may not be worded quite as carefully, but that is what it is.

   - Those suggesting fruit-topped pastries that are 'pizzas' or went too close to the idea of a rocky road pizza are, in my opinion, not correctly answering the question.  They are taking liberties.
3. Someone who answers the question with a stellar idea for a dessert pizza that fits the criteria deserves their rep.  I would think this even if I didn't have an answer in the running.

Others can feel free to disagree, but I think that this question should be viewed as I outlined above and answered as such rather than closed.

An example of a question I'm still debating over would be [Curries Made from Scratch: a Beginner's Guide](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9171/curries-from-scratch-a-beginners-guide).  It's so overly broad.  On the other hand, the current single answer has the right advice - get a book from the acknowledged leading expert and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad to see people asking this, although I have more or less answered it already in the new meta-FAQ, [What is Community Wiki?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/what-is-community-wiki/914#914)

To break it down as simply as possible:

- If a question seems too subjective/open-ended to stand up as a *normal* rep-gaining question, **vote to close.**  In other words, follow the guidelines at [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/); if it passes most of those criteria then the question is fine as it is.  Otherwise, it doesn't belong here at all.
- If you deem a question too open-ended but think that it is because of the *phrasing* of the question (as opposed to its actual subject matter) then **edit it** or, if you lack the privilege, **leave constructive criticism for the author** suggesting how it could be improved.
- If and only if the question appears to be *blatant rep-farming* and of *absolutely no value to the community*, **then** flag it for moderator attention; one of us will likely close the question (if it hasn't already been closed) **and** wiki it to stave off any rep-gaming taking place.

Remember, just because a question is fun/interesting doesn't mean it's appropriate here.  We should try to "save" questions whenever we can with judicious editing and comments, but ultimately it now comes down to a more black-and-white decision about whether or not the question belongs.  The community wiki "gray area" is dead.  Questions shouldn't normally be community wiki anymore, only answers.

Sometimes "list"-like questions can actually be answered normally; for example, see the answer to [What things are good to spherize with algin?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9032/41)  This was handled as a real question, *not* a poll.  The problem with these questions is not always the questions themselves but also the way people have been conditioned to answer them - by blurting out ideas without any explanation whatsoever.  If you don't see that happening, then you don't really need to worry about the question.

This adjustment is probably going to be tough for a lot of people, so everyone reading this has to try to be a role model; if a good question is getting a lot of noise in the answers then don't be afraid to downvote some of those answers for being poorly-written.  At the very least, don't upvote answers that appeal to you on a subjective level but aren't supported or explained.  Don't necessarily flag the *question*, though, unless you think the situation is getting out of control.  Either vote to close if it's truly irredeemable or edit/comment if you think it can be clarified.

**P.S.** I'd like to point out for the record that just about any question with the word "ideas" in the title is exactly the type of question that *does* need attention, either in the form of editing or closure.  In the case of this specific example, I think some fairly small edits could take care of the poll-ish-ness.