# Where can we ask questions about meal planning and recipes?

Tags: discussion, recipes

I don't really find Seasoned Advice to be helpful in its current state for my needs, but that's just me (this isn't a critique). I would like to find help regarding recipe/menu selection though, Lot of help and advice on it actually. Is there a place for those kinds of questions in Stack Exchange? If not, will it come to SA in the future or a different Stack site?

Answer (score 3):

There actually was a recipes proposal created as a [response to a much older meta discussion](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/create-a-recipes-meta-site/358#358).

Unfortunately, the proposal no longer exists.  I'm pretty sure it was auto-deleted due to inactivity and not deliberately deleted by a moderator.

Seems like there was never really much support for a Q&A site for recipe polls, but that *was* a long time ago, so I guess you could always try starting another proposal.

As for an existing site - no, there is no dedicated site for that.

Note that [we are still trying to figure out how to do menu planning properly](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/41), which covers topics such as side dishes, portion sizing, etc. - those questions are on topic here but our community has struggled a bit with regard to the "formation" of those questions (as well as their answers), and if you have any thoughts on that, please do contribute to the linked discussion.

But if you're just looking for recipes, then to be honest, I'd recommend taking your sights off the SE network and using the many available [recipe resources](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2500/41) and [recipe searches](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12736/41), or reading the blogs of well-known foodies.  I'm not saying that *only* for our benefit - I honestly believe that those types of resources will *always* be better than a Q&A site, since recipe selection is highly dependent on personal tastes, and you'll get more of what *you* want if you're able to filter the recipes according to *your* preferences as opposed to what a lot of anonymous voters think.

Comment: Recent proposal: [Recipe Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/81523/recipe-recommendations)

Comment: @kenorb: There was already a previous proposal with the same name that was shut down. I suppose Software Recommendations has set a new precedent, but it's only been allowed to go forward on the basis of having very *focused* recommendations based on things like feature lists - in other words, questions with a relatively small number of "correct" answers. To date, I have never seen a recipe request get close to that bar, and I'm not encouraged by the questions on that proposal so far.